# Mostrar imágenes en React usando props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy entrando en el mundo de React.

Quiero mostrar imagenes de acuerdo a al prop devuelto para completar el nombre de la imagen, estoy usando `require` para tratar de mostrar la imagen.

Si como la direccion manualmente si me la muestra, pero usando la inserción de JS no me lo permite

Dejo el link del ejercicio en codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-hodgkin-x1gyu1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una recomendacion es que utilizes destructuring con los props, asi no tendras que ir añadiendo props.loquesea.

He puesto la carpeta de img en el directorio Public y funciona:

```
import React from "react";
import "../styles/testimonio.css";

function Testimonio({nombre, pais, cargo, empresa, testimonio, imagen}) {

    return (
        <div className="contenedor-testimonio">
            <img
                className="imagen-testimonio"
                src={`/img/Testimonio-${imagen}.png`}
                alt="Foto de Emma"
            />
            <div className="contenedor-texto-testimonio">
                <p className="nombre-testimonio">
                    {nombre} en {pais}
                </p>
                <p className="cargo-testimonio">
                    {cargo} en {empresa}
                </p>
                <p className="texto-testimonio">"{testimonio}"</p>
            </div>
        </div>
   );
 }
 export default Testimonio;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Revisa la edición, he quitado la variable y he puesto el codigo directamente en el src, así está mejor.

Comment: Ya lo había intentado pero ahora si funciono, quizás tenia alguna letra mal